# Fuctional equation with derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

Supose $f,g$ and $h$ are in $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$f^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^ng^{(k)}h^{(n-k)}.$$

Is there a simple way to obtain $f$ in terms of $g$ and $h$ such that $f$ does not depend on the derivatives?

I try with Leibniz derivation product rule, but the binomial coefficients implies to many problems.

Comment: Is that equation valid for a specific $n$, some given set of $n$, or for any $n \geq 0$?

Comment: Does $f = g h$, work?

Comment: Is for fixed $n$

Comment: $f=gh$ doesn't work, cause $f^{(n)}=\sum C_k^nh^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$ (Leibniz Product Rule)